# How can I change selected item color in non editor panel of Eclise?

Tags: eclipse, uicolor

I am Using Eclipse Neon 3 with darkest dark theme. The color of text and background of selected items are very similar in Project explorer, Search and any other non editor panel as shown below so it is very hard to read . Anyone know how I can change them?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxY0C.png)

Comment: Well I found the solution. The highlight color is applyed system wide so I had to change the color theme of Gnome GTK Theme.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the solution. The highlight color is applyed system wide so I had to change the color theme of Gnome GTK Theme with Gnome Tweak tool.